# Testing dates Date.now() in reducer initial state my test case was failing

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

I was testing my reducers with Jest but at the initial state, I was having `Date.now()`, when I was testing expected time and received time is different by few milliseconds.

This is my reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  scroll: Date.now(),
};
export default function clearStore(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CLEAR_STORE: {
      return INITIAL_STATE
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This is my testing code:

```
import clearStore from "./clear-store";


const INITIAL_STATE = {
    scroll: Date.now()
};

it("testing default case", () => {
    const posts = INITIAL_STATE
    const newState = clearStore(undefined, {});
    expect(newState).toBe(posts);
})
```

I was receiving:

```
Object {
  -   "scroll": 1633947823739,
  +   "scroll": 1633947823591,
}
```

Comment: The initial state in the implementation is set when the module is imported, there's no guarantee the test will run in the same millisecond. Treat time as a dependency, so you can control it in your tests.

Comment: I think this test is a little bit useless. What you are testing? If redux reducer works? For sure it works, redux developers already tested it. Try to focus your tests on your logic (that could be bugged). Just a suggestion.